# Sorting a list based on a field on each of its members

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have the following `List`, which contains items of type `ENTITY`. `ENTITY` has an integer field which determines its natural ordering. I want to get the `ENTITY` which is the maximum or minimum based on that field's value. How can I implement this in Java?

```
List<ENTITY> lt = new ArrayList<ENTITY>();

class ENTITY
{
    int field;
    /* Constructor, getters, setters... */
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is no research efforts from OP.

Comment: I know write a custom comparer is  one of the way to implement it, any other better way ?

Comment: @silentprogrammer And not even an attempt at vaguely correct Java.

Comment: @chrylis I agree, and other users should also understand that SO has some standard which should be maintained by not encouraging these type of questions.

Comment: If you two think my question is easy, can you help to figure out a way implemented in Java 7 however having the Java 8 stream API style? Of course I know the way Comparator and stream API, however what I needed is the stream API style in Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//stream the elements, map to their fields, and get the max
return lt.stream().max((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.filed, e2.filed)).orElse(/* default */);
```

Just one of the many applications of Java 8's stream api.

Though I would suggest working on some coding conventions first.

Comment: we just working on the Java 7 and we cannot use the Java in our environment

Comment: It's the same concept, you merely iterate the elements of your list, and find the one with the value you're searching for (e.g. the max `filed` value). These are basic java concepts, if you haven't gone over loops I'd suggest starting here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: I want to a way similar to Java 8  stream api, however working on the Java 7

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) with a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort your list. Depending on whether you sort ascending or descending, the positions of the max and min elements will differ. In either case, they will be at opposite ends, one at the top of the list and one at the bottom. To sort in ascending order (smallest element at the beginning of the list, largest at the end) you can use something like this:

```
Collections.sort(lt, new Comparator<ENTITY> {
    public int compare(ENTITY o1, ENTITY o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            if (o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        // If field is Comparable:
        return o1.getField().compareTo(o2.getField());

        // OR - If field is an int
        return o1.getField() < o2.getField() ? -1 : (o1.getField() > o2.getField() ? 1 : 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems I still need to write a custom comparer , it seems there is no easy way to implement it  like stream api in Java 8

Comment: @Jason Not sure what you mean by an "easy way"...the few lines of code above aren't particularly difficult. The Stream API isn't available in Java 7, but people were sorting lists and finding max and min values long before Java 8 was conceptualized.